# How can I play C&C Generals over wireless LAN?

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals

Me and my friend have *Command & Conquer: Generals* and we want to play it using wireless. My laptop is the server. I create an ad hoc wireless network and enable network discovery and sharing on both, so the computers can find each other. I also disable firewall on my laptop and his.

When we want to connect to each other using *direct connect* or other methods, it fails.

I know the game is very old but I really want to play, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but Given the age, it may still have been wanting to use IPX for networking instead of IP.

Comment: @Zoredache that was it, post your comment as answer and I make it answer!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of methods you can try:

1. Make sure both of your computers are on the same network (sounds like you've tried this but it should work)
2. If you're not both within the one house you can use VPN such as hamachi https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/

**Important** You must both have identical versions of Generals. I.e. if you are on version 1 (or the unpatched equivalent) then your friend must also be on the same.

Once you're both on the same network of some sort and you both have identical versions it should be as simple as creating a game in the LAN lobby. You or your friend should be able to see the game on lobby list.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to play on LAN using this method: "just download a client from http://www.planethamachi.com/ and add some servers to your list and you will be able to play zero hour on the "multiplayer>>networks" option."
Source: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080211225847AAoydgL

Answer (score 0):

My experience with a lot of gamenights (multiple games with multiple OS platforms) over the years learned that a wireless network will always cause connection troubles with one or more PCs or laptops. The best way is to connect the old fashioned way: ethernet cables with one or more switches. Routers will also work but can also cause trouble.

I bought and old second hand 24 port switch: literally plug-and-lay every time!